# Selecting dynamically generated rows to delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hi I have a following table outputs rows of data. There is a delete button next to each row.

```
           <form>
             <table id="tblAppendGrid" class="appendGrid">
                <thead class="ui-widget-header">
                <tbody class="ui-widget-content">
                <tr id="tblAppendGrid_Row_1">
                <td><input type="text" id="tblAppendGrid_s_1" name="nameCompany"    maxlength="100" style="width: 160px;"></td>
                <td><button id="tblAppendGrid_Delete_1" class="delete ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" value="2" type="text" title="Remove Current Row" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="false"></td>
                <tr id="tblAppendGrid_Row_2">
               <td><input type="text" id="tblAppendGrid_s_2" name="nameCompany" maxlength="100" style="width: 160px;"></td>
               <td><button id="tblAppendGrid_Delete_2" class="delete ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" value="2" type="text" title="Remove Current Row" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="false"></td>
           </tbody>
           <tfoot class="ui-widget-header">
           </table>
        </form>
```

I am trying to read a row when a delete button is clicked. As in code below I dont know how to pick the row number next to button id. Because of that it is not working.

```
      $(document).ready(function () {

           $("#tblAppendGrid_Delete_").button().click(function () {

                        testing("in delete");
                    });    
       });
```

I guess I need the selector be like $("tblAppenDGrid_Delete_2"). ...
Please let me know how can I select this row on button click so I can remove it. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here

ID of an element must be unique, you have multiple elements with id `tblAppendGrid_Delete_`, in this case you can use a class value to group all the delete buttons instead of ID attribute.

```
<button class="tblAppendGrid_Delete_1 delete ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" value="2" type="text" title="Remove Current Row" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
```

Since you might be dealing with dynamic elements you need to use event delegation based event handlers

```
$(document).on('click', ".tblAppendGrid_Delete_", function () {
    testing("in delete");
});
```